# How to link ExtraPropertiesExtension to custom extension in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How can I configure and link `ext` to `customExtension` in my custom Gradle-plugin?

Buildscript:

```
customExtension {
    name = 'name'
    ext {
        set('url', 'https://...')
    }
}
```

Custom plugin:

```
project.getExtensions().configure(CustomExtension.class, customExtension -> {
    customExtension.setName("name");
    ???ext???
}
```

Don't figure out how to configure and link ExtraPropertiesExtension to custom Extension.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Extra properties are for users to put arbitrary things into, not for plugin authors to use, if you already have an `CustomExtension` then add the `url` property to that one.

Comment: The `url` property is not a part of the `CustomExtension`, it configures in the `ext` inside `CustomExtension`. The question is how to configure and link `ext` to `CustomExtension`? (how to turn groovy buildscript into Java code in a custom Plugin)

Comment: Got it, just cast ext to `ExtensionAware`.
`ExtensionAware customExtension = (ExtensionAware) project.getExtensions().getByType(CustomExtension.class);
ExtraPropertiesExtension customExtensionExtraProperties = customExtension.getExtensions().getExtraProperties();`